# PHP - date string to Mysql dateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, type-conversion

I have to convert a string like 
'Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:35:01 +0000'
to a MySQL dateTime in PHP which can be entered straight into the db, could someone help please?
btw, I have no use of the +0000
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime()` can convert this easily:

```
$dt = new DateTime('Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:35:01 +0000');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/c8GFbK)

Comment: Or if you're using PHP 5.5+: `echo (new DateTime('Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:35:01 +0000'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`